# Saving outputs from arcpy.da.Walk to the same folder

Tags: arcpy, mosaic, walk

I have a number of sub-directories within my "BP Tiles" directory. Each of these sub-directories represents a different year (2016, 2017, 2018, etc.) and within each of these sub-directories is a list of raster layers. I am attempting to use the Walk module to mosaic each list of Raster layers within the individual year directories. 
[See Code Source](https://community.esri.com/thread/160519)

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# SET GEO_PROCESSING ENVIRONMENTS
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\BP_Tiles"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(env.workspace, topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    print
    dirpath
    rasterList = []
    for file in filenames:
        raster = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        rasterList.append(raster)
    try:
        arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasterList, dirpath, + "Mosaic.tif", "", "", "", 1)
    except:
        pass
```

The code is set up to save the output "Mosaic.tif" within each sub-directory. I'd like to manipulate this code such that all of the Mosaics are saved to the same output folder. Id also like to append the sub-directory name (Ex. 2016) to each output such that I know how to differentiate the outputs.

Would anyone happen to know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All of the Mosaics are saved to the same output folder.

Instead of using `dirpath` when creating your new raster use the same path each time.

```
outPath  = r"C:\some\path"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    .... #other code
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasterList, outPath, "Mosaic.tif", "", "", "", 1)
```

2. Append the sub-directory name (Ex. 2016) to each output such that I know how to differentiate the outputs

Update `"Mosaic.tif"` with the sub-directory name.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    ....#other code
    dirName = os.path.basename (dirpath)
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(rasterList, outPath, "Mosaic_{}.tif".format (dirName), "", "", "", 1)
```